# how to refractor common set state functions in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have two or more components that shares common function that sets some local states.
How do I refractor so that I don't repeat the function.

Code:
**Component 1:**

```
function Trending({ authors, books }: HomeProps) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [book, setBook] = useState<BookProps | null>(null);

  const handleBookClick = (book: BookProps) => {
    setBook(book);
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
    setBook(null);
  };
 return ( // some code) 
}
```

**Component 2:**

```
function Saved({ authors, books }: BookProps[]) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [book, setBook] = useState<BookProps | null>(null);

  const handleBookClick = (book: BookProps) => {
    setBook(book);
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
    setBook(null);
  };
 return ( // some code) 
}
```

I tried exporting the function from on component and calling it in another but it says the setOpen and setBook isn't defined which I dint.

Any good approach to refractor and make the function common.

Comment: Are they both called by the same parent component ? If so put the logic in the parent component and pass them as props. You could also use context.

Comment: You can lift those states up and put them in a parent component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to write a custom hook to reuse component logic, for example this way:

```
   export const useBooks = () => {
      const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
      const [book, setBook] = useState<BookProps | null>(null);

      const handleBookClick = (book: BookProps) => {
        setBook(book);
        setOpen(true);
      };

      const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
        setBook(null);
      };
     return {
      book,
      open,
      handleBookClick,
      handleClose
     }
    }




And then use it in the component as below:



    import {useBooks} from 'hooks/useBook'

    function Saved({ authors, books }: BookProps[]) {
      const {handleBookClick, handleClose, open, book} = useBooks();
  

enter code here

      return ( // some code) 
    }
```